# It's possible to execute one script when i add a new file to one folder?

Tags: windows

I want to make a script on windows to move my files on folde1 to folder2 when i add some new file in folder 1, is it possible or at least any part of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can use:

- Powershell ([example](https://superuser.com/questions/226828/how-to-monitor-a-folder-and-trigger-a-command-line-action-when-a-file-is-created))
- Batch file, with or without task scheduler (example on link above)
- Task Scheduler and a VBScript ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762064/windows-file-monitoring-script-batch-vbs))
- VBScript and WMI __InstanceModificationEvent event ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762064/windows-file-monitoring-script-batch-vbs))
- .NET's FileSystemWatcher ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760904/how-can-i-monitor-a-windows-directory-for-changes))
- Third party software (some [suggestions](https://superuser.com/questions/468662/how-to-monitor-a-folder-for-changes-and-execute-a-command-if-it-does-on-window))

Answer (score 2):

Concept is called DirectoryWatcher/FileWatcher, you can google it by these keywords for your programming language. It's represented in most languages now.